# Adobe Indesign SWF Export - Hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink, adobe, adobe-indesign

I've been using Indesign to create some brochures. I export them as SWF to display them as a flip book.

The next step I want to take is to put hyperlinks on each product in my brochure so that when a user clicks them the item gets added to their shopping basket, or something similar.

First I tried using a hyperlink value of ?product=code, but as there's no http://, whenever you open this link it just opens a blank tab.

Secondly I tried a hyperlink value of http://linktosite.com/flipbook.php?product=code. This worked fine but as the users may want to order several products from the catalogue they're going to click on a lot of the links, which will in turn open up loads of new tabs in the browser.

My question is: Is there a way of passing hyperlink values through the same page the SWF is on? I don't want the links to open a new tab everytime.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the end? I am trying to do something similar, namely I would like the link to be "javascript:dosomething('buttonID');", but Indesign won't let me.

Comment: I ended up exporting to FLA, which puts the brochure into Flash, 1 spread per frame. Then you can use actionscript to do the work. Only downside of this is that u cant export with the page curl when exporting to FLA, so you have to create your own in Flash. This thread helped:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/2975696#2975696

Answer (score 2):

Indesign cs5.5 has new feature called 'web viewer'in windows/extensions/overlay creator. This let you browsing another website in indesign file.